# c++ windows - Disable crash dialog box in a child process

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I have a program that launches a child process.
When the child process crashes I would like there not to be a debug message box. I would like to do this without writing anything in the child process.

I am running this on windows 7.

In the createProcess function, in the flags parameter I only put CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE.

During my attempts, I put SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS|SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX) in the child process and made it crash, there was no dialog box. Now I put the same function call in the parent program before I called create process, and made the child program crash, now the message box appeared.
What should I do differently?

Comment: when you set the error mode in parent, have you cehcked if it is inherited using GetErrorMode?

Comment: Can you paste code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

have you set CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE in process creation flags?

Comment: as I understand, I am not supposed to, but I tried both with and without